# ReflectionTypeLoadException: Type is attempting to implement an inaccessible interface

Tags: c#, reflection, typeloadexception

I'm using *Assembly.GetTypes()* for getting all types defined by in a plugin library (so I can instantiate plugin instances).

On a particular library, the method raise a ReflectionTypeLoadException, saying:

```
Type <Type> is attempting to implement an inaccessible interface
```

Googling it seems because the specific *Type* implements a non-public interface. And actually it is, but the *Type* is nested in another public class, declared as private.

How avoid this exception?

....

Made interface public the code works. Is it possible to define this strange behavior is a bug (in Assembly.GetTypes())? This imply that a library type cannot implement a protected interaface!

Comment: It's silly to give the host a hard time to instantiate a type.  Assembly.GetTypes() should *never* be necessary.  Give the factory class a good name.

Comment: @Hans, are you suggesting the factory class should have a specific namespace *and* name that a host would expect so that they could grab the `Type` directly?

Comment: @*Hans Passant* It seems reasonable. But the basic problem is not resolved yet. What if the type is not public and implements a non-public interface?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was solved by removing the protected *nested* type from the public type.

Answer (score 3):

I faced same issue while MessagePack serialization. I was trying to implement interface in internal class so it thew this exception "from assembly 'MessagePack.Resolvers.DynamicObjectResolver, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is attempting to implement an inaccessible interface."
So I took that internal class out of its container class in same namespace below is my before and after code...
Before....

```
using MessagePack;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class CallbackReciever
    {

        [MessagePackObject]
        public class SampleCallback : IMessagePackSerializationCallbackReceiver
        {
            [Key(0)]
            public int Key { get; set; }

            public void OnBeforeSerialize()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OnBefore");
            }

            public void OnAfterDeserialize()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OnAfter");
            }
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            SampleCallback b1 = new SampleCallback { Key = 1 };

            Console.WriteLine("Starting serialization");
            byte[] data = MessagePackSerializer.Serialize<dynamic>(b1);

            foreach (byte b in data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(b);
            }

            SampleCallback temp = MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<SampleCallback>(data);
            Console.WriteLine(MessagePackSerializer.ToJson(temp));
        }
        }
}
```

After....

```
using MessagePack;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    [MessagePackObject]
    public class SampleCallback : IMessagePackSerializationCallbackReceiver
    {
        [Key(0)]
        public int Key { get; set; }

        public void OnBeforeSerialize()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnBefore");
        }

        public void OnAfterDeserialize()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnAfter");
        }
    }
    class CallbackReciever
    {



        public static void Main()
        {
            SampleCallback b1 = new SampleCallback { Key = 1 };

            Console.WriteLine("Starting serialization");
            byte[] data = MessagePackSerializer.Serialize<dynamic>(b1);

            foreach (byte b in data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(b);
            }

            SampleCallback temp = MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<SampleCallback>(data);
            Console.WriteLine(MessagePackSerializer.ToJson(temp));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        }
}
```