# Create type that implements internal interface

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose I have assembly that declares internal interface `IInternalInterface`. I have no access to code of this assembly and I can't change it. 
How can I create my own implementation of `IInternalInterface`?

Why I need this: the assembly contains the class with list of `IInternalInterface` implementers  and my goal is to add my own implementation there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I to create my own implementation of IInternalInterface?

Simple answer: you can't. If the authors of the assembly decided to mark this interface with `internal` it means that they didn't want code from other assemblies to use this interface.

Comment: oh yes you can.. using Reflection.Emit .. but beware of the dragons.

Comment: @noah1989, you can't use Reflection.Emit to generate a class that implements an internal interface. When you try to load this dynamic class you will get a TypeLoadException exception at runtime.

Comment: Indeed.. "Type '...' from assembly
'...' is
attempting to implement an inaccessible interface."

Comment: I need a complicated answer :)

Comment: @Orsol, there isn't. You are pretty much toasted if you cannot *touch* at the source code of the assembly containing this interface.

Answer (score 9):

It is possible using remoting proxy.
Note that my answer is just a quick sketch and might need to be improved further.

```
internal interface IInternalInterface {
    void SayHello();
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// in another assembly
public class ImplementationProxy : RealProxy, IRemotingTypeInfo {
    private readonly MethodInfo method;

    public ImplementationProxy(MethodInfo method) 
        : base(typeof(ContextBoundObject))
    {
        this.method = method;
    }

    public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage msg) {
        if (!(msg is IMethodCallMessage))
            throw new NotSupportedException();

        var call = (IMethodCallMessage)msg;
        if (call.MethodBase != this.method)
            throw new NotSupportedException();

        Console.WriteLine("Hi from internals!");
        return new ReturnMessage(null, null, 0, call.LogicalCallContext, call);
    }

    public bool CanCastTo(Type fromType, object o)
    {
        return fromType == method.DeclaringType;
    }

    public string TypeName
    {
        get { return this.GetType().Name; }
        set { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I will extend the answer from @AndreyShchekin as it was really useful but missed some bits:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var internalType = typeof(PublicTypeInAnotherAssembly).Assembly.GetType("Full name of internal type: System.Internals.IInterface");

        var result = new InterfaceImplementer(internalType, InterfaceCalled).GetTransparentProxy();
    }

    static object InterfaceCalled(MethodInfo info)
    {
        // Implement logic.
        Console.WriteLine($"{info.Name}: Did someone call an internal method?");
        // Return value matching info.ReturnType or null if void.
        return null;
    }
}

public class InterfaceImplementer : RealProxy, IRemotingTypeInfo
{
    readonly Type _type;
    readonly Func<MethodInfo, object> _callback;

    public InterfaceImplementer(Type type, Func<MethodInfo, object> callback) : base(type)
    {
        _callback = callback;
        _type = type;
    }

    public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage msg)
    {
        var call = msg as IMethodCallMessage;

        if (call == null)
            throw new NotSupportedException();

        var method = (MethodInfo)call.MethodBase;

        return new ReturnMessage(_callback(method), null, 0, call.LogicalCallContext, call);
    }

    public bool CanCastTo(Type fromType, object o) => fromType == _type;

    public string TypeName { get; set; }
}
```

Now `result` is assignable to the internal interface. To verify it, we can do this in the assembly containing the internal interface:

```
public class PublicTypeInAnotherAssembly
{
    public void Test(object proxy)
    {
        var internalInterface = (IInternalInterface)proxy;

        internalInterface.MethodOnInterface();
    }
}
```

Or assign it with **reflection** if we don't have access.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use assembly version redirection or type redirection to "move" the interface declaration to an assembly under your control and make your implementation public.

But as Darin said, be sure to double-think about this approach. There may be an intended way to extend the library functionality that would be much cleaner...

Comment: What is version redirection or type redirection?

Comment: @Orsol: Google is pure Magic! here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.71).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404275.aspx

Comment: @Orsol: You could make a "fake" assembly that redirects everything to the original one but adds your interface implementation. Not sure if this works but even if it does it's quite a dirty hack.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to redirect only the interface to a newly created assembly and make it public there? but as said, welcome to the dark side ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this is impossible. Even if you manage to make a class that implements that interface using Reflection.Emit, you won't be able to use it because you will get a [ReflectionTypeLoadException: Type is attempting to implement an inaccessible interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350363/reflectiontypeloadexception-type-is-attempting-to-implement-an-inaccessible-int)

Answer (score -1):

You could add `[InternalsVisibleTo()]` attribute, but as far as you have no access to source code, **you can't implement this interface at *compile time***

<strike>From the other hand, you can do it **at run time.** For this you should use runtime code generation (also known as `Reflection.Emit`) and fetch the interface type with `BindingFlags.NonPublic`. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478218/using-reflection-emit-to-implement-a-interface).</strike>

**UPDATED:**
As mentioned in comments below, it is impossible to inherit from a non-public interface. So unfortunately you have **no solutions**.

Comment: Nope. I thought that would work, but it [doesn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350363/reflectiontypeloadexception-type-is-attempting-to-implement-an-inaccessible-int).